# loggin in with curl

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I'm trying to get the below cURL operation to login on a bangme.net picture rating site. When I inspect the login form, the IDs are signin_UserName, signin_UserPass. The names are signin$UserName, signin$UserPass. The script doesn't seem to work with the underscore as the result leads me to a page that asks me to login as far as I can tell. I'm not able to use the dollar sign names as it turnes it into a variable. I notice some examples of this and similar scripts show some fields starting with the '&' sign when it doesn't have that on the form on the webpage for which they want to login to. What does this do? Any assistance you can provide would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$url = "http://www.bangme.net/starform.aspx";
$cookie = "cookie.txt";

$postdata = "signin_UserName=" .$username . "signin_UserPass=" .$password;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

new code:

```php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$url = "http://www.bangme.net/signin.aspx";
$cookie = "cookie.txt";

$post = array(
        '__EVENTTARGET'=>"" ,
        '__EVENTARGUMENT'=>"",
        '__VIEWSTATE'=>"/wEPDwUJMzQ0MjU1MjA0ZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAwUJbGFzdHBob3RvBQh2b3RleWVzMgUHdm90ZW5vMgfkai25gOMuDdbmzYMWHA2LgYKt",
        '__EVENTVALIDATION'=>"/wEWDgLmnpGMBwKOwMbqCwK4wb4IAv/10agEAqHH7a8KAtXfk+ULAt/Q94gCAvS2udYOAqrdhtcHAq+k5d0LAo+Au5MKApm/3+0OAqDCuuYMArCmgTeosqrEgmB3P5bavC40rTc6dbeF1g==",
        'signin$UserName'=>$username ,
        'signin$UserPass'=>$password ,
        'signin$Button1.x'=>42,
        'signin$Button1.y'=>17
        );

$postData = http_build_query($post);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);//changed from 0 to 1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//new
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);//new


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 thing wrong here

A. Wrong variable declaration ....

Correction

```
 $post = 'signin$UserName=' . $username . '&signin$UserPass=' . $password;
```

B.  Wrong Url

Correction

```
 http://www.bangme.net/signin.aspx
```

C.  Parameters not complete System Expects the following :

**EDIT 1**

```
$post = array(
        '__EVENTTARGET'=>"" ,
        '__EVENTARGUMENT'=>"",
        '__VIEWSTATE'=>'/wEPDwULLTEyMzUzNDExNjFkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCBRdzaWduaW4kUmVtZW1iZXJDaGVja2JveAUOc2lnbmluJEJ1dHRvbjFA3HLFp6KEVYvii7p6PjecyYMsaw==',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION'=>'/wEWBQL/xuPVDgLCoo75CQKoiOf4DQKtwMGFDgLz0rmTDUnuxoGtW34gNpQqIpwh3OT11JJl',
        'signin$UserName'=>$username ,
        'signin$UserPass'=>$password ,
        'signin$Button1.x'=>42,
        'signin$Button1.y'=>17
        );
$postData = http_build_query($post);
```

**Edit 2**

Full Headers ... Just noticed it also had cookies

```
POST http://www.bangme.net/signin.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bangme.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 391
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://www.bangme.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.bangme.net/signin.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=1jqjwt45h0gpzb452rvrcu55; __utma=178887351.705741064.1333412926.1333412926.1333412926.1; __utmc=178887351; __utmz=178887351.1333412926.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=178887351

__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTEyMzUzNDExNjFkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCBRdzaWduaW4kUmVtZW1iZXJDaGVja2JveAUOc2lnbmluJEJ1dHRvbjFA3HLFp6KEVYvii7p6PjecyYMsaw%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWBQL%2FxuPVDgLCoo75CQKoiOf4DQKtwMGFDgLz0rmTDUnuxoGtW34gNpQqIpwh3OT11JJl&signin%24UserName=test&signin%24UserPass=test&signin%24Button1.x=42&signin%24Button1.y=17
```

**EDIT 3**

Change

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Thanks

:)

Comment: Thank you baba, can you tell me how to implement the paramaters you describe in C?

Comment: and how you determined those parameters were required?

Comment: That is what is posted when you click on submit

Comment: Ok, so I kept getting an 'object moved here' screen so I added some things I found from other stackoverflow posts regarding that. I now get the site's we are too busy try back in 30 minutes page displayed however I do not outside of this script. You mention cookies, is there something more I need to do with that? I have edited my post above with my current code

Comment: Ugh, I didn't get my original post updated before you updated yours lol.

Comment: I get the site too busy try back in 30 minutes message still. Let's forget about that for a second. There is a message box with a submit button I'd like to post a message too which would only work if I was authenticated. Do I need to create a separate curl session after the first one to do this or do I create it within the first? Thank again for helping me with this. I appreciate it

Comment: YES! I got it! Gosh I could have saved myself hours of banging my head on the table if I just would have copied the __EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATE values right. Thanks for your examples!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the form field names with the dollar signs; you need to either escape the `$` so it isn't interpreted as a variable, or stick it in single quotes so it is only evaluated as plain text.

```
$post = 'signin$UserName=' . $username . '&signin$UserPass=' . $password;
// or
$post = "signin\$UserName=$username&signin\$UserPass=$password";
```

Try that and see if you make any progress.  Sniff out the request in your browser using something like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) or [livehttpheaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) which help you see the exact format post data being submitted.

See also [PHP - Strings - Single Quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Comment: thank you for your response, it helped my original question. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're just missing an ampersand (`&`) between your two post parameters.

And to deal with the $ in the input fields names just use `\$` (escaped dollar sign) in your code or put the parts with the $ signs into single quotes. (But then you have to put all variable references outside the string and concatenate them with a `.`)